# how do i fix such an error; uncaught TypeError

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, abi

The error that I am facing is as said
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abi' of undefined

These are the codes

```
FilmRegistrationApp.prototype.init = function(cb) { 
    this.web3 = new Web3(
        (window.web3 && window.web3.currentProvider) || 
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(this.Contract.endpoint));
    var contract_interface = this.web3.eth.contract(this.Contract.abi);
    this.instance = contract_interface.at(this.Contract.address);
    cb();

}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError` means that the object you are trying to use does not exist in that point of code yet.

Answer (score 3):

Have you assigned your object `this.contract`? With the file (or object) that have properties: endpoint, abi, address?
Thats what it's unable to find.